# Saving camanjs image after adding new layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, camanjs

I am trying to download a canvas (with canvas.toBlob()) created with camanjs after it applies a new layer.  I can only get it to download the image without the applied layer.  I can right click and "save as..." to get the correct image but the downloaded file is incorrect.

```
Caman("#myImage", function() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('myImage');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    this.newLayer(function() {

        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src = "some_image.png";

        imageObj.onload = function() {
            context.drawImage(imageObj);
        };
    });
    this.render(function() {
        saveCanvas();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippet which converts the canvas image with multiple layers to base64 and save as JPEG. If you want to save in some other format like "png" then just
give "download.download = 'image.png'" in the below code

```
saveCanvas(){
        var download = document.createElement('a');//Create <a> tag
        download.href = document.getElementById('myImage').toDataURL(); //convert canvas image with multiple layers to base64
        download.download = 'image.jpeg'; // Mention the file name and format to be downloaded
        download.click();// Trigger click event to downkload the image
    }
```